# Changing Default Download Destination for RemoteWebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, remotewebdriver

Im trying to set the default download directory to some thing like:

```
_webServerFolderDirectory = @"D:\Web\FreshPlatformRegression1\RegressionTestResources";
```

but i am having no luck finding anything anything to do so. I can find solutions for `ChromeDriver` (See the line i commented out) but nothing that'll work with `DesiredCapabilities` for `RemoteWebDriver`. Here is what the part the calls up the `RemoteWebDriver` looks like at the moment:

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();
//cap.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", _webServerFolderDirectory);
            
cap.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
_parallelConfig.Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://192.168.1.98:4455/wd/hub"), cap);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Incase anyone comes across this issue, I have found a solution. You can use `.ToCapabilities()` to convert `ChromeOptions` to capabilities. The code would look similar to this:

```
String downloadFilepath = @"\\rslfgweb\FreshPlatformRegression1\RegressionTestResources\PDFReports\";
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.AddUserProfilePreference("download.default_directory", downloadFilepath);

_parallelConfig.Driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://192.168.1.98:4455/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities());
```